# Why am I getting an "invalid header or archive is corrupted error" (Stable Diffusion)?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, conda

I'm a newbie with Stable Diffusion and I don't understand why I am getting this error when trying to generate images:

```
File "/Users/me/miniconda3/envs/ldm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 997, in load_tensor storage

= zip_file.get_storage_from_record(name, numel, torch._UntypedStorage).storage()._untyped()

RuntimeError: PytorchStreamReader failed reading file data/11: invalid header or archive is corrupted
```

This happens when I run

```
python scripts/txt2img.py --prompt "a drawing of web developers" --plms --ckpt sd-v1-4.ckpt --skip_grid --n_samples 1
```

Any idea what causes this? I've unsuccessfully tried to use older weights.

Comment: If you can provide an example image and specific code to recreate this error, you are more likely to get a helpful answer